# The Quartz API version is not recognized in Java project

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to integrate quartzdesk in my Java app and I am receiving the errors below:

```
[2016-08-23 16:51:22,347] W [main] [com.quartzdesk.agent.scheduler.quartz.instrument.c:124] - Skipped instrumenting of org.quartz.core.jmx.QuartzSchedulerMBean class loaded from jar:file:/srv/updaters/applications/app/channelmax-to-ods-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/lib/quartz-2.2.1.jar!/ because the Quartz API version is not recognized.
[2016-08-23 16:51:22,347] I [main] [com.quartzdesk.agent.scheduler.quartz.instrument.c:129] - org.quartz.core.jmx.QuartzSchedulerMBean class class-loader:
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@3ffcd140
  file:/srv/updaters/applications/.quartzdesk-libs/quartzdesk-api-2.5.0.jar
  jar:file:/srv/updaters/applications/app/channelmax-to-ods-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/
```

Please help to fix this problem.

Comment: The problem was the quartzdesk version 2.5 has a problem in Spring Boot applications. The problem was fixed on version 2.6.1

Comment: I'm also trying to embed quartzdesk in my spring boot application but found that the installation guide is fairly vague. Could you please share some steps you took to get it to work? What is the url to access quartz desk in the spring boot app? Your advise is much appreciated!